# Parse URLs from HTML code C++

Tags: c++, html, parsing, network-programming, web-crawler

I'm creating a simple web crawler in C++. At the moment I've managed to get the HTML code from an seed URL, saved in either an string or text file.

**How can I find and save the URLs in the HTML I want to continue my web crawling?**

Comment: By parsing the HTML in the files you read. Note: It's *not* trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this robustly, you need a proper HTML parser. [Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) is an open source HTML5 parser written an opensourced by Google that you can use to implement something like this.